# EF access navigation properties in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an entity like below

```
public class Role
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public bool HasPermission(String code)
    {
        foreach (var p in this.Permissions)
        {
            if (p.Permission.Code.Equals(code))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and in controller, this code run fine:

```
for (var p in db.User.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).First().Role.Permissions) { PrintToDebug(); }
```

but:

```
User ur = db.User.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).First();
ur.Role.HasPermission("Some_Code_Were_Defined");
```

then the `Permissions` list in `HasPermission` always has a zero length, why and how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

This is occurring because of Entity Framework Lazy Loading.  In your first statement, you are specifically requesting the `Permissions` property, which causes Entity Framework to generate a query that loads that table from the database.  In the second query, you are only asking Entity Framework to load the `User` table from the database, but the `HasPermission` method you are calling has no way of making another database call to load the `Permissions` table.

This is a common issue when working with Entity Framework.  It can be resolved by using the `Include()` extension method from Entity Framework to eagerly load the related table in the second query, i.e. `User ur = db.User.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).Include(u => u.Role.Permissions).First();`

Comment: Why does "*the HasPermission method you are calling has no way of making another database call to load the Permissions table*"? `HasPermission` accesses `this.Permissions` internally. Why doesn't lazy loading work here while it works in the first code snippet? (`Include` certainly gives the wished result, but I'm not convinced by your explanation why it's necessary...)

Comment: Yes, lazy loading should still occur if the DbContext is not disposed (if disposed, it would throw an exception when it attempts to lazy load).